# What stat does the Kusarigama scale with?

Tags: nioh

In *Nioh*, there is a weapon called the Kusarigama. It's one of the five starting weapons you can choose from, and happens to be the one I chose.

The issue I've run into now, is I'm not sure which stat the Kusarigama scales with. All of the stats have descriptions, such as "Affects damage with swords/axes/spears," but the Kusarigama are not mentioned alongside any stat. So, just which stat do I need to increase to maximize my effectiveness with the Kusarigama?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprisingly, I've found that ***three*** stats increase the damage of my Kusarigama. These are **Dexterity**, **Skill**, and **Body**. In the images below, you can see that each of these tree skills increases my Kusarigama (melee weapon 1) by one point each.

[image: dexterity]

[image: skill]

[image: body]

Though I am low level at the moment and all stats increase my Kusarigama's power by one point, these stats are, in fact, scaled differently, as you can see from the item's page. I have circled the portion that lists stats that scale with the weapon.

[image: item page]

You can check any weapon's page to see how stats affect them. All weapons scale with 3 stats.

- Axes scale with **Body**, **Stamina**, and **Strength**.
- Kusarigama scale with **Body**, **Skill**, and **Dexterity**
- Single *and* Dual Swords scale with **Heart**, **Strength**, and **Skill**.
- Spears scale with **Body**, **Strength**, and **Skill**.

Comment: Same to Dark Souls and Bloodborne, weapons in Nioh have scaling depending on certain stats, on of which is strongest. I suppose, this stat has corresponding weapon listed in description. And for most Kusurigamas which we can see, Dexterity is top scaling.

Comment: Ah, okay. I was looking in the wrong place, it seems. Oops. :(

Comment: @Fluttershy it's okay, I only just found it. I didn't notice before, either.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, I can't check it in the game at the moment, but according to [this Wiki page](http://nioh.wiki.fextralife.com/Stats), Kusarigama damage is affected by Dexterity stat. I will update info once I can get confirmation in-game.

Comment: I also chose the Kusurigama as my starting weapon and I *think* there was a second stat that affected the Kusurigama damage. I may be wrong, though, because I'm using the special edition DLC weapon rather than the Spy Kusurigama that most people start with.

Comment: Oh huh. It's so odd to me that they don't mention that in-game like all the other weapons. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It depends, it mainly stacks with dexterity however this only becomes noticeable after putting a fair few points into it, originally skill and dex both increase the weapon damage by 1 for about 10 or so levels.